# SQL trigger: BEFORE UPDATE OF

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I have a following schema in my *sqlite3* database.

It is a table that stores user's bid on a product, and triggers that I use to offload a validity check from my application code.

The goal here is to check whether a new bid is larger than the previous one and if not then raise an error to the application. It works well for `INSERT`, but `UPDATE` raises error even when `NEW.amount` is actually the largest bid for a given product.

I cannot figure out why is this happening mainly because triggers are impossible to debug. A suggestion on this would also be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bids (
    amount INTEGER NOT NULL,
    product_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    submitted DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS trig_beforeinsert BEFORE INSERT ON bids
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN
            ((SELECT MAX(amount) FROM bids WHERE product_id = NEW.product_id) >= NEW.amount)
        THEN
            RAISE (FAIL, "invalid amount")
    END;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS trig_beforeupdate_amount BEFORE UPDATE OF amount ON bids
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN
            ((SELECT MAX(amount) FROM bids WHERE product_id = OLD.product_id) >= NEW.amount)
        THEN
            RAISE (FAIL, "invalid amount")
    END;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this was an application specific error I could have figured out before posting here.